# How to create multiple instances of an object within Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create multiple instances of an object and store it in an array. However, the last instance of it overwrites the previous ones. Is their a way I can create each individual object?

I've tried creating an array and filling each individual object separately. I've also tried creating new instances of it.

```java
class Card {
 private static String name;

 public Card(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
}

public class Main {
 static Card[] deck = new Card[5];
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  deck[0] = new Card("Ace");
  deck[1] = new Card("Club");

  System.out.println(deck[0].getName());
  System.out.println(deck[1].getName());
 }
}
```

The output of deck[0] should be "Ace" while deck[1] should be "Club". 
What is outputting is "Club" twice. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't make `name` static.

Comment: its not the instance that gets overriden is your static variable.

Comment: Here is the good source to understand the use of static keyword: https://www.baeldung.com/java-static

Answer (score 2):

The field `name` in your class `Card` is declared `static`. Remove the `static` keyword:

```
class Card {
 private String name;
 // ...
}
```

If something is `static` there can be only one.